# eclipse opencv 3.1.0 library compiler issues on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, opencv, compiler-errors

For University I need to make a few c++ projects with **Opencv (version 3.1.0)** in eclipse. 
I have linked the include and libraries of opencv like suggested in the tutorials and eclipse does indeed highlight the variables correctly.

But once I try to compile the project I get the following error(s):

> g++ -L"C:\opencv\build\x64\vc14\lib" -o "DisplayImage2" 
>   ./src/DisplayImage.o   -lopencv_world310 -lopencv_world310d
>
> C:\Users\eclipse-cc-workspace\DisplayImage2\Debug/../src/DisplayImage.cpp:11:
>   undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
>
> C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:625: undefined
>   reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long long)'

The same for any operator defined in **opencv**, not only **imread**.

from what I have gathered until now, these errors happen if the libraries `-lopencv_imgcodecs` and similar are not linked in other versions of Opencv. 
But on the 310 windows version there aren't any of these libs. The only one that there are are `opencv_world310` and `opencv_world310d` which I already have linked. 
So I don't know why the gnu compiler doesn't find the declarations.

I tried other versions of opencv but all above 310 (which I need) only have opencv_world as their combined libraries.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve the problem, but certainly is wrong: you are linking the debug and release library, you should link the one with the `d` to a debug build and the other one to a release build.

Comment: I tried it only with opencv_world310 and that doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you and I have seached and tried a lot and finally had a conclusion. It seems that g++ cannot work with opencv_world310, but MSVC cl.exe can directly link opencv_world310 and works well. If you want to use g++, you should use cmake with opencv souce file first.